# Какой скрипт использовать для формы обратной связи с аттачем

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, вёрстка

Нужно сделать форму обратной связи с аттачем, перерыл уже гору подобных скриптов, но все тщетно либо скрипты не рабочие попадаются либо какая то проблема с хостингом, подскажите какой лучше использовать для таких целей? Или может подскажете как добавить обработчик к стандартному скрипту обратной связи или любому другому?

В качестве стандартного используется вот этот

```js
<?php
 $msg_box = "";
 $errors = array();
 if($_POST['user_name'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваше имя' не заполнено!";
 if($_POST['user_email'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваш e-mail' не заполнено!";
 if($_POST['text_comment'] == "") $errors[] = "Поле 'Текст сообщения' не заполнено!";

 if(empty($errors)){  
  $message  = "Имя пользователя: " . $_POST['user_name'] . "<br/>";
  $message .= "E-mail пользователя: " . $_POST['user_email'] . "<br/>";
  $message .= "Текст письма: " . $_POST['text_comment'];  
  send_mail($message);
  $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;'>Сообщение успешно отправлено!</span>";
 }else{
  $msg_box = "";
  foreach($errors as $one_error){
   $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
  }
 }

 echo json_encode(array(
  'result' => $msg_box
 ));
 
 
 function send_mail($message){
  $mail_to = "some@mail.com"; 
  $subject = "Письмо с обратной связи";
  
  $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: Тестовое письмо <no-reply@test.com>\r\n";
  
  mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
```

Comment: Так а проблема в чем? Если что, `mail` работает не всегда...

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= "From: Тестовое письмо <no-reply@test.com>\r\n";
```

Во From должен быть адрес в домене=сайта, с которого отравляется форма. И это адрес должен быть заведён на хостинге (на домене сайта `test.com` завести мыло `no-reply@test.com`). А адрес отправителя нужно подставлять в reply-to.

В любом случае все ошибки см логах.